# Java client + NTLM Authentication 401

Tags: java, url, windows-authentication

I'm new in java and I got project to exchange data via WebRest API with one system.
So, normal procedure, I need to send CURL or URL to system and take information, but first I need to go throw authentication. On the server with this system, authentication is set on Windows authentication with NTLM. I tested URL link with JMeter, and I get correct answer.
But when I try to comunicate from my aplication then I always have error 401.
I checked a lot of post about authentication, but a lot of was old and not working.
Here is my code:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
            System.setProperty("http.auth.ntlm.domain", "web104.server.local");
            // System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "domain");
            System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", "ADMINISTRATOR");
            System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", "Password");
            System.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.hostname", "web104.server.local");
            System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "65200");
            URL urlRequest = new URL("http://web104.server.local:65200/public/api/sessions/v1/sessions/actions/login");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlRequest.openConnection();

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                String str = "";
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(str);
                }
                in.close();

                System.out.println(response);
            } catch (IOException err) {
                System.out.println(err);
            } finally {
                Map<String, String> msgResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();

                for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
                    String headerName = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
                    String headerValue = conn.getHeaderField(i);
                    if (headerName == null && headerValue == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    msgResponse.put(headerName == null ? "Method" : headerName, headerValue);
                }

                System.out.println(msgResponse);
            }

        }
    }
```

Do you have any idea, why I got always error 401?

Answer (score 0):

the code 401 means server requires auth, the auth setting is invalid. Make sure you have the **jcifs** set:

```
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "jcifs");
```

or

```
jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
```

Per documentation, the above are two ways to setup, you set both, please keep only one.

Another idea is set username and password in url.

Ref: [jcifs httpclient](https://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/httpclient.html)